# Running uname -m Gives x86_64 On M1 Mac Mini

Tags: macos, mac-mini, apple-silicon

When I run `uname -m` in zsh (run via Terminal.app) on my M1 Mac Mini, the output is `x86_64`, instead of the expected `arm64`. This is occurring both in zsh and in bash. This is causing issues with installing native ARM wheels with pip, which thinks that I am running an x86 system. I couldn't find any information online about this, and am wondering if it is a bug, or something that I have overlooked. Any ideas of what is going on? Is this expected behavior? I am running macOS 11.3.1. The following other information is output by `uname`:

`uname: Darwin`

`uname -a: Darwin macmini.local 20.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Thu Apr 22 21:46:41 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 x86_64`

`uname -p: i386`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce what you are seeing on our Macs on 11.2.3 and 11.3.1 - we get **arm64 / arm / arm64** reliably back despite different shells and homebrew (or lack thereof) setups on each.

```
bmike@mini ~ % sw_vers                 
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.3.1
BuildVersion:   20E241
bmike@mini ~ % /usr/bin/arch
arm64
bmike@mini ~ % /usr/bin/uname -p
arm
bmike@mini ~ % /usr/bin/uname -a
Darwin mini 20.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.4.0: Thu Apr 22 21:46:41 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.101.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
```

Choosing rosetta to run terminal changes this for a stock Mac. Quit and start again terminal.app, and I then get **i386 / i386 / x86_64** the same as you reported.

- https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/37723/rosetta-2-extension-attribute

If you look below, you'll see it enabled which will launch a shell that reports what you are seeing as opposed to the results "out of the box" that I showed above.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean "I can NOT reproduce (unless I run Terminal in Rosetta)."..?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, which I noticed in attempting to install Homebrew with M1 support. Homebrew's installation script uses `uname -m` to determine which Homebrew to install, and so was giving me the wrong (Intel) version because it was detecting me as `x86_64`.

It turns out that my problem was described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65259300/detect-apple-silicon-from-command-line#comment124415881_65259353)

> it's not just if running Terminal in Rosetta, but also if whatever process runs the script happens to be running in Rosetta too. If someone runs this in a script deployed by, say, an RMM that is running via Rosetta you'll get x86_64

My problem was that my `bash` itself was installed by the old Intel Homebrew, and was itself running through Rosetta.

```
$ file `which bash`
/usr/local/bin/bash: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I needed to switch to the system `bash` by running

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

and reconfigure my `$PATH` such that `/bin/bash` was preferred. Now `uname -m` always gives me the expected `arm64`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem without using Rosetta.

It turned out the reason was that I installed homebrew before it had M1 support. Even though I frequently upgrade homebrew, it didn't switch to the Apple Silicon version when it became available.

Reinstalling homebrew solved the issue for me.

Comment: Good point. Homebrew for ARM needs to be specifically installed, upgrading the Intel version will not migrate it.